# how do we reset the checkbox `react-google-recaptcha` after form submission in a redux application,

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

So I have a redux application that has a file called LoginForm,(just the form elements) and I have another file called LoginFormContainer(formik is responsible) for form values. Now how do I reset the captcha in this case? considering the fact that the ref is on the LoginForm file,

tries the ref approach but I couldn't get it to work since these are two files that know nothing about each other in terms of the ref.

**This is the component I created and  a using the react-google-recaptcha**

```
import React from "react";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

interface OwnProps {
  onChange(value: any): any;
}

const ReCaptcha: React.FunctionComponent<OwnProps> = (props) => {
  const { onChange } = props;
  const recaptchaRef = React.useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null);
  const siteKey = String(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SITE_KEY);

  return (
    <>
      <ReCAPTCHA
        ref={recaptchaRef}
        sitekey={siteKey}
        size="normal"
        onChange={onChange}
        theme={"dark"}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ReCaptcha;
```

**This is the form that collects the data**

```
import { Field, Form, InjectedFormikProps } from "formik";
import * as React from "react";


    export const LoginForm: React.FunctionComponent<
      InjectedFormikProps<{}, LoginFormValues>
    > = (props) => {
      const { isSubmitting, setFieldValue } = props;
    
      function onChangeCAPTCHA(value: any) {
        setFieldValue("captchaToken", value);
      }
    
      return (
        <Form>
          <FormFieldsWrapper>
            <Field type="email" label="Email" name="email" component={TextInput} />
          </FormFieldsWrapper>
          <FormFieldsWrapper>
            <Field
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              name="password"
              component={TextInput}
            />
          </FormFieldsWrapper>
          <FormFieldsWrapper>
            <ReCaptcha onChange={onChangeCAPTCHA} />
          </FormFieldsWrapper>
          <FormFieldsWrapper>
            <Button
              fullWidth={true}
              primary={true}
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              loading={isSubmitting}
              type="submit"
              style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
            >
              Login
            </Button>
          </FormFieldsWrapper>
        </Form>
      );
    };
    
    export default LoginForm;
```

**This is the container where form values are being sent to the back-end**

```
import { withFormik } from "formik";
...

interface PropsFromState {
  authenticated: boolean;
  location: Location;
}

interface PropsFromDispatch {
  loginPromise: typeof loginPromise;
}

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email("Please enter a valid email")
    .required("Email is required"),
  password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
  captchaToken: Yup.string().required("Please select CAPTCHA"),
});

type AllProps = PropsFromState & PropsFromDispatch;

class LoginFormContainer extends React.Component<AllProps> {
  public render() {
    let from = { pathname: "/tenants", search: this.props.location.search };

    const { authenticated } = this.props;

    if (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.from) {
      from = this.props.location.state.from;
    }

    if (!authenticated) {
      return <Wrapper>{this.renderForm()}</Wrapper>;
    }

    return <Redirect to={from} />;
  }

  private renderForm() {
    const formikEnhancer = withFormik<{}, LoginFormValues>({
      displayName: "LoginForm",
      handleSubmit: async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        try {
          await this.props.loginPromise(values);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } finally {
          setSubmitting(false);
        }
      },
      mapPropsToValues: () => ({ email: "", password: "", captchaToken: null }),
      validationSchema: schema,
    });
    const EnhancedLoginForm = formikEnhancer(LoginForm);

    return <EnhancedLoginForm />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, router }: ApplicationState) => ({
  authenticated: auth.authenticated,
  location: router.location,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  ...bindPromiseCreators({ loginPromise }, dispatch),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginFormContainer) as any;
```

Comment: You need to provide code to get some help

Comment: @Johan I added some code, please have a look when you have a moment

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have 2 approaches:

Approach 1:

```
//LoginForm.js
const LoginForm = () => {
    const recaptchaRef = React.useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null);

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={() => recaptchaRef.current.reset()}>
            ...
            <Recaptcha ref={recaptchaRef} onChange={onChange} />
            ....
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Approach 2:

```
// LoginForm.js
const LoginForm = () => {
    return (
        <FormWithRecaptcha>
            ...
        </FormWithRecaptcha>
    );
}

//FormWithRecaptcha.js
const FormWithRecaptcha = (props) => {
    const recaptchaRef = React.useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null);

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={() => recaptchaRef.current.reset()}>
            <Recaptcha ref={recaptchaRef} onChange={onChange} />
            {props.children}
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Comment: remember that the <Form> component is coming from an import from formik. so this `onSubmit={() => recaptchaRef.current.reset()` throws an error

Comment: As per the documentation, you can wrap with `Formik` component and pass `onSubmit` to it. https://formik.org/docs/api/formik